# Pose array's variance converge(navigation stack, amcl)

Tags: navigation, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm using nav stack with my robot.
I'd like to set a final variance of a robot pose array.

I set amcl's parameters **"update_min_a" and "update_min_d" to 0.0**
because I'd like to have the robot estimate its pose
even if it stops.

In this case, a pose array showen on rviz converges as soon as amcl node runs.
It's what I like, but **the array over-converges.**
I mean, **all arrows showing robot's pose lie on top of each other.**

I guess that some threshold is offered to avoid that.
However, I changed all parameters listed in amcl's wiki and couldn't find 
which one is it.

Could you tell me **which parameter is used to avoid the above problem?**

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54276/pose-array%27s-variance-converge(navigation-stack,-amcl)/) by [moyashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/2104/moyashi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 721 on 2013-02-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can do that through increasing "laser_sigma_hit" value in amcl parameter.

---

Originally posted by [Anas Alhashimi](https://answers.ros.org/users/10201/anas-alhashimi/) with karma: 179 on 2014-09-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0